# CodeIgniter CSS trouble

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am having a very strange problem, when I use CSS `:hover` in a `td` in a static HTML file, it works fine (see the navigation bar on http://www.nutricioncelular.es/REGISTRATE.html)

When I use it in a CodeIgniter view however, (code is the same, see http://www.nutricioncelular.es/index.php) the red color on `td` background doesn't work. The code is exactly the same, and the call to the view is a simple load view with no parameter, no data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for the two pages are **not** exactly the same - the PHP view using CodeIgniter has this in front of the `doctype` declaration, triggering Quirk Mode and thus breaking your CSS:

```
<html>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Inca</TITLE>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </HEAD>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: omg, i thought i had tested it but... there was a header view loader before the actual view, in was in the class constructor..

Answer (score 0):

This is really very strange,

```
.MENUCELDA:hover
```

class is not applying in php version of application, but it I modified it to

```
td.MENUCELDA:hover
```

is working as expected in php version site.